# Going through 'Vue Basics - Instant prototyping' - running 'vue serve' fails

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to execute 'vue serve' using my installed vue cli.

I've done the following:

1. npm -g install @vue/cli   <-- works ok.
2. npm -g install @vue/cli-service-global  <-- seems to install package ok.

I then try to execute a 'vue serve' command and receive the error:

"Command vue serve requires a global addon to be installed.
  Please run npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global and try again."

vue cannot see the addon.

Any know why ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try with sudo:  `sudo vue serve`

Comment: are you sure you want to do `vue serve`? the command to start the dev server is often `npm serve` (or `yarn serve`), when run from the command line. There's also the command `vue ui` to start the new `vue-cli-3` gui...

Comment: You may try the order they show: `npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global` or `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global` - perhaps this is not a real difference, but it doesn't hurt trying...

Answer (score 0):

Check your **@vue/cli** and **@vue/cli-service-global** package versions.  If the versions are not compatible, that could be the issue.

Also, are you running this on a Windows machine but from a MING terminal?  I've had subtle permission issues with trying to run @vue/cli from a non-windows terminal.  You might try deleting your **node_packages/** directory and running **npm install** from a **Windows Command Prompt** if you are on a Windows machine.